# Difference between constants, arbitrary constants and variables in differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The general solution of the differential equation $y''+\omega^2y=0$ can be written as: $$y=\alpha\cos{(\omega(t-c))}+\beta\sin{(\omega(t-c))}$$
Is it correct to say that:

1. $\omega$ and $c$ are constants
2. $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are **arbitrary** constants
3. $t$ is a variable

QUESTION: What is the difference between **constants**, **arbitrary constants** and **variables**?

Comment: Yes, all three are correct.

Comment: You've got solution of DE. That's function depend of **variable**. Now exactly you've got family of solutions, because of **arbitary** constants (if there are initiall conditions, you could find this **arbitary** constants). 
So it's easy to say: **variable** - smth that you could change, **arbitary** constants - smth, that you could find (if there are initall conditions) and constants - some numbers from DE.

Comment: I don't see why $c$ is not arbitrary in the same sense that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are. Usually, the solution is given by, either $\alpha \cos (\omega (t-c))$ or $\alpha \cos \omega t + \beta \sin \omega t$. In any case, you have two arbitrary constants, because your equation is second order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is totally correct.
The solution of the equation, the function, depends on the value of t (called, the variable).
Also, the constants are properties of the system described by the differencial equation (the elasticity of a material or the mass of a pendulum, etc...), while the arbitrary constants give diferent solutions depending on the initial conditions of the system (for example, the initial phase of a mass connected to a spring).

Comment: How about the comment of @user40085? Why shouldn't $c$ be also an arbitrary constant? Meaning, isn't $c$ part of the initial conditions?

Comment: @ImreVégh In the case of the constant c, it may depend on the nature of the system and its oscilating properties. It is true that sometimes, the c constant is arbitrary because it is the initial phase of the oscilations, but in some scenarios like in control engineering it is not. So it's an interesting question because c may depend on the context.